# Running DOOM and DOOM 2 with DOS

Tags: doom, doom-2, msdos

Does anybody know how to install DOOM I and II in MS-DOS 6.22? I already have DOS installed on a windows millennium computer, and DOOM I and II on floppy disks. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Wow. How old is your computer?

Comment: about 1999 is when it was made

Comment: Wow again! that's older than me. Guess my age!

Comment: What? You're pretty young!

Comment: Well, i am too, so whatever

Comment: I still go to school. [This](http://www.hillgrovesec.moe.edu.sg/) is my school website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24380/discussion-between-thecodingmonster-and-find-me-in-the-woods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You... put the first disk in the floppy drive and run:

```
a:
setup.exe
```

Install should be the first option in the menu that appears.

On a modern system, it's just easier to install Doom 3: BFG Edition, which includes both Doom 1 and 2.

Edit: Or to install Doom 1 and 2 from Steam.

Comment: well, okay. do I have to mount the disk or anything? or do I just say "setup.exe"

Comment: @FindMeInTheWoods The floppy drive is usually the a drive, do you'd have to do an `a:` first.

Comment: so, `a: setup.exe`

Comment: is that it? it just runs?

Comment: Having said that, you should seriously consider using one of Doom's source ports.  I've heard [zDoom](http://zdoom.org/) is one of the better ones, but I'm not sure if it runs on Windows ME.

Comment: I wiped the disk. It is FULLY MS-DOS 6.22

Comment: @FindMeInTheWoods Once Doom is installed, it should have a doom.exe in C:\doom or wherever it installed to.